# HTML5 audio menu isnt opening in my simple webpage

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple webpage with some audio. But for some reason it's menu isn't opening on clicking on 3 dots. Pls advice

The audio is nothing fancy:

```html
<audio controls="controls" style="max-width: 233px">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

I dont know what is wrong.

[link to webpage](https://imi-preview.netlify.com/?bot_unique_name=entity_test_dev&enterprise_unique_name=ayeshreddy.k&root=dev)

Comment: The code in the question works fine. The problem must be something you didn't include here. Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: it doesn't work because of your animation on .chat-body .message-wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just uncheck the **`animation-fill-mode: forwards;`** from my google chrome browser, it works, see my image

[image]